# Extract key/value pairs from $http response in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, pattern-matching

I have a rest call to a server which returns me something that looks like this:

```
response.searchResult = ["{\"key1\":\"value1\",
                          \"key2\":\"value2\",
                          \"key3\":\"value3\"}"]
```

How can I extract all key-value pairs into a json array? Or at the very least, how can I search for the value associated with a specific key, lets say `"key2"` from the example?

Comment: can you do like this JSON.parse(["{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\",\"key3\":\"value3\"}"])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run json.parse on the array entry:

```
response.searchResult = ["{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\",\"key3\":\"value3\"}"];
var jsonResult = JSON.parse(response.searchResult[0]);
console.log(jsonResult);
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, thank you Mathew :).